# Why can't i use the method data() in my streambuilder in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Why can't i use the method `.data()` ?

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream:
              usersDb.doc(widget.allUsersFromDb.docs[index]["uid"]).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              ));
            }
            // List? invitedByArray = snapshot.data!.data() not working
            return Text("Invite");
          },
        ),
```

Comment: What error is it showing when you use data()?

Comment: The method data() isn't defined for the type Object

Comment: found my issue the snapshot was an async snapshot by default i need to declare it as a documentSnapshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to be clear if you don't specify the `StreamBuilder` type it will be an `<AsyncSnapshot>` by default
The solution was to put the `StreamBuilder` as a `<DocumentSnapshot>`

```
 StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: usersDb.doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, currentUserDocSnapshot) {
              if (!currentUserDocSnapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                ));
              }
              return Text(userSelectedSnapshot.data!["username"]);
            },
          );
```

You can then access the `.data` method and access your document values

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).